# Requesting static files in node.js and event loop

Tags: node.js

Does requesting a static file, say an image from a static directory, use the event loop and cause any blocking of the main thread? It is even dealt with by the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "requesting static file from a static directory"? If you mean web-server case(like one express.js does for you) it is certainly is. And while call itself isn't really blocking (in case of async call) it certainly takes some time to make that call and process results. In other words, if you want to host static content use nginx (and you will end up using it anyway if you decide to balance traffic between two machines, for instance).